# rEFInd configuration?

Tags: refind

I am trying to get my acs-patched Antergos kernel to boot from rEFInd. It was detected automatically by rEFInd but it did not boot properly. I kept on getting `ERROR: device 'UUID=...' not found. Skipping fsck.`, so to bypass this, and have the kernel parameters, I tried a custom menuentry, which fails. No information at all, only a black screen. Additionally, I would like to get the rEFInd-minimal theme working.

Normal Antergos boots perfectly fine, after I manually select it from rEFInd submenu and XUbuntu still works fine.

A note about the theme, the custom Antergos icon works, but the banner does not, nor overriding icons for XUbuntu or normal Antergos.

rEFInd is setup on a separate partition like so:

**/dev/sda**:

```
| EFI BOOT | Empty Partition |  SWAP  | XUbuntu | Antergos | Free Space |
|  1.0 GB  |     1.0 GB      | 8.6 GB |  21 GB  |  40 GB   |   185 GB   |
```

**EFI BOOT**:

```
.
└── EFI
    ├── BOOT
    │   ├── bootx64.efi
    │   ├── drivers_x64
    │   ├── icons
    │   ├── keys
    │   └── refind.conf
    ├── refind
    │   ├── rEFInd-minimal
    │   └── refind-theme-regular
    └── tools
```

**refind.conf**:

```
timeout 20

menuentry "Antergos IOMMU" {
    icon EFI/refind/rEFInd-minimal/icons/os_antergos.png
    volume Antergos
    loader /boot/vmlinuz-linux-vfio
    initrd /boot/initramfs-linux-vfio.img
    options "root=/dev/sda5 rw quiet iommu=pt amd_iommu=on"
}

hideui singleuser,hints,arrows,badges

icons_dir EFI/refind/rEFInd-minimal/icons

banner EFI/refind/rEFInd-minimal/background.png
banner_scale fillscreen

selection_big EFI/refind/rEFInd-minimal/selection_big.png
selection_small EFI/refind/rEFInd-minimal/selection_small.png

showtools shutdown
```

***/dev/sda5*/boot/**:

```
.
├── grub
│   ├── fonts
│   ├── grub.cfg
│   ├── grub.cfg.example
│   ├── grubenv
│   ├── i386-pc
│   ├── locale
│   └── themes
├── initramfs-linux-fallback.img
├── initramfs-linux.img
├── initramfs-linux-vfio-fallback.img
├── initramfs-linux-vfio.img
├── intel-ucode.img
├── vmlinuz-linux
└── vmlinuz-linux-vfio
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after some time, (mostly just ignoring this and bypassing it by manually editing the refind boot each time, annoyingly) I figured out this problem.

The problem was refind.conf file.

First, the theme was fixed like so:

```
#old
icons_dir EFI/refind/rEFInd-minimal/icons

banner EFI/refind/rEFInd-minimal/background.png

selection_big EFI/refind/rEFInd-minimal/selection_big.png
selection_small EFI/refind/rEFInd-minimal/selection_small.png

#new
banner ../refind/rEFInd-minimal/background.png

selection_big ../refind/rEFInd-minimal/selection_big.png
selection_small ../refind/rEFInd-minimal/selection_small.png

icons_dir ../refind/rEFInd-minimal/icons
```

Using a relative path worked.

The menu entry was the problem for booting the VFIO kernel.

```
# Did not work
menuentry "Antergos IOMMU" {
    icon EFI/refind/rEFInd-minimal/icons/os_antergos.png
    volume Antergos
    loader /boot/vmlinuz-linux-vfio
    initrd /boot/initramfs-linux-vfio.img
    options "root=/dev/sda5 rw quiet iommu=pt amd_iommu=on"
}

# Works
menuentry "Antergos IOMMU" {
    icon EFI/refind/rEFInd-minimal/icons/os_antergos.png
    volume Antegros
    loader /boot/vmlinuz-linux-vfio
    initrd /boot/initramfs-linux-vfio.img
    options "root=UUID=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx ro iommu=pt amd_iommu=on pcie_acs_override=downstream"
}
```

So, the real issue was that my label for my Antergos installation was misspelled (Antegros). Since the label has little bearing in my system, changing the label in the menu entry was the main fix. I also setup the root using the UUID (although /dev/sdx should work as well).